# Run script on remote host not in play

Tags: ansible

I am trying to include the running of a script on a remote host before completing a set of tasks on another list of hosts.  Specifically I am trying to execute a script on my local yum repo, to sync the repo, before running a yum update on a set of hosts.  The local repo server can't be in the same inventory list as the hosts being updated, so how would I accomplish this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why couldn't you add the host storing the yum repository to the inventory? I think that adding it to the inventory and putting hosts being updated in a group would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I see to possible answers. Pick the one best suited to your situation

## Solution 1: 2 plays

An ansible playbook can contain several plays that will be run in order. You can seperate your operations in two plays. This will probably be more convenient if you have several tasks for your first host, or if you have several hosts to talk to for your sync (i.e. cluster...)

```
- name: sync my local yum repo
  hosts: my_local_yum_repo_host

  tasks:
    - name: dummy task to sync repo
      debug:
        msg: sync repo

- name: update my hosts
  hosts: my_hosts_to_upgrade

  tasks:
    - name: run the upgrade
      yum:
        name: '*'
        state: latest
```

## Solution 2: delegation and run_once

In this case we put everything in the same play and use [delegation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) with [`run_once`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) to play a single time for all hosts to update in the list

```
- name: update my hosts
  hosts: my_hosts_to_upgrade

  tasks:

    - name: dummy task to sync repo
      debug:
        msg: sync repo
      delegate_to: my_local_yum_repo_host
      run_once: true

    - name: run the upgrade
      yum:
        name: '*'
        state: latest
```

Comment: Thank you for your great reply Zeitounator. The problem I see with either option, and I should have included this in my original question, is that I have three different lists of servers to run this play against and I only want to run the sync when it is the first group.  To my understanding you can't have a when statement in a play.

Comment: You can put a when statement on the delegated task in the second option.

Comment: Oh really?  That helps a lot.  Thank you!